# SignalR - Same dashboard data (fetch from queries) using different browser. SignalR/hub , mvc, c#.net

Tags: javascript, c#, css, model-view-controller, signalr-hub

> I'm having a problem with my signalr/hub. I'm fetching data for my dashboard with dates using 2 browsers.
> When I'm searching for the month of July using browser 1, datas are displayed. Then when I try to search another month using browser 2, browser 1's datas were changed. Its now same with b
>
> C#.net MVC

```
public class DashBoardBroadcaster
{

    private DashboardManager dashboardmanager = new DashboardManager();
    private readonly static Lazy<DashBoardBroadcaster> _instance = new Lazy<DashBoardBroadcaster>(() => new DashBoardBroadcaster());
    private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
    //private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    //private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;
    private Timer _broadcastLoop;



    public DashBoardBroadcaster()
    {
        // Save our hub context so we can easily use it 
        // to send to its connected clients.
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DashBoardHub>();
        // Start the broadcast loop
        _broadcastLoop = new Timer(BroadcastSend, null, BroadcastInterval, BroadcastInterval);
    }


    public void BroadcastSend(object state)
    { 
       
        List<transaction_details> newloan = new List<transaction_details>();
        List<transaction_details> renewal = new List<transaction_details>();
        List<transaction_details> redemption = new List<transaction_details>();
        List<transaction_details> partialpayment = new List<transaction_details>();
        List<transaction_sales_details> jewelrysales = new List<transaction_sales_details>();

        transaction_details datanewloan = new transaction_details();
        transaction_details datarenewal = new transaction_details();
        transaction_details dataredemption = new transaction_details();
        transaction_details datapartialpayment = new transaction_details();
        transaction_sales_details datajewelrysales = new transaction_sales_details();
        
        if (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch == null)
        {
            
            newloan = new List<transaction_details>();
            renewal = new List<transaction_details>();
            redemption = new List<transaction_details>();
            partialpayment = new List<transaction_details>();
            jewelrysales = new List<transaction_sales_details>();

            datanewloan = new transaction_details();
            datarenewal = new transaction_details();
            dataredemption = new transaction_details();
            datapartialpayment = new transaction_details();
            
        }
        else
        {
            string monthzero;
            List<List<transaction_details>> myNewLoanMontlyList = new List<List<transaction_details>>() { };
            List<List<transaction_details>> myRenewalMontlyList = new List<List<transaction_details>>() { };
            List<List<transaction_details>> myRedemptionMontlyList = new List<List<transaction_details>>() { };
            List<List<transaction_sales_details>> mySalesMontlyList = new List<List<transaction_sales_details>>() { };

            List<int> monthly_newloan_data_ID = new List<int> { };
            List<decimal> monthly_newloan_data_debit = new List<decimal> { };
            List<int> monthly_renewal_data_ID = new List<int> { };
            List<decimal> monthly_renewal_data_debit = new List<decimal> { };
            List<int> monthly_redemption_data_ID = new List<int> { };
            List<decimal> monthly_redemption_data_debit = new List<decimal> { };
            List<int> monthly_sales_data_ID = new List<int> { };
            List<decimal> monthly_sales_data_selling = new List<decimal> { };

            string datedaily;
            string datemonthly;
            string monthlyonly;

            if (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datedaily == null)
            {
               // datedaily = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                //datemonthly = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                monthlyonly = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-");

            }
            else
            {
               // datedaily = (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datedaily).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

               // datemonthly = (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datemonthly_from).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                monthlyonly = (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datemonthly_from).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-");

            };

          
            //newloan = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily, "N-");

            for (int i = 0; i < Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items; i++)
            {
                if (i < 9)
                {
                    monthzero = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    monthzero = "";
                };
                List<transaction_details> transactionmonthlynewloan = dashboardmanager.Get_MonthlyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, (monthlyonly + monthzero + (i + 1)), "N-", Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items);
                myNewLoanMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlynewloan);
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items; i++)
            {
                if (i < 9)
                {
                    monthzero = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    monthzero = "";
                };
                List<transaction_details> transactionmonthlyrenewal = dashboardmanager.Get_MonthlyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, (monthlyonly + monthzero + (i + 1)), "R-", Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items);
                myRenewalMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlyrenewal);
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items; i++)
            {
                if (i < 9)
                {
                    monthzero = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    monthzero = "";
                };
                List<transaction_details> transactionmonthlyredemption = dashboardmanager.Get_MonthlyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, (monthlyonly + monthzero + (i + 1)), "FR-", Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items);
                myRedemptionMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlyredemption);
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items; i++)
            {
                if (i < 9)
                {
                    monthzero = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    monthzero = "";
                };
                List<transaction_sales_details> transactionmonthlysales = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyMontlySalesTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, (monthlyonly + monthzero + (i + 1)), "j", Globals.dashboard_request_daily.no_of_items);
                mySalesMontlyList.Add(transactionmonthlysales);
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < myNewLoanMontlyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myNewLoanMontlyList[i].Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var internal_monthly_newloan_data in myNewLoanMontlyList[i])
                    {
                        monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data.ID);
                        monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_newloan_data.Debit);
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    monthly_newloan_data_ID.Add(0);
                    monthly_newloan_data_debit.Add(0);
                };
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < myRenewalMontlyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myRenewalMontlyList[i].Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var internal_monthly_renewal_data in myRenewalMontlyList[i])
                    {
                        monthly_renewal_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_renewal_data.ID);
                        monthly_renewal_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_renewal_data.Debit);
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    monthly_renewal_data_ID.Add(0);
                    monthly_renewal_data_debit.Add(0);
                };
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < myRedemptionMontlyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myRedemptionMontlyList[i].Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var internal_monthly_redemption_data in myRedemptionMontlyList[i])
                    {
                        monthly_redemption_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_redemption_data.ID);
                        monthly_redemption_data_debit.Add(internal_monthly_redemption_data.Debit);
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    monthly_redemption_data_ID.Add(0);
                    monthly_redemption_data_debit.Add(0);
                };
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < mySalesMontlyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (mySalesMontlyList[i].Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var internal_monthly_sales_data in mySalesMontlyList[i])
                    {
                        monthly_sales_data_ID.Add(internal_monthly_sales_data.ID);
                        monthly_sales_data_selling.Add(internal_monthly_sales_data.SellingPrice);
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    monthly_sales_data_ID.Add(0);
                    monthly_sales_data_selling.Add(0);
                };
            };


            string datedaily1;
          
            if (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datedaily == null)
            {
                datedaily1 = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");



            }
            else
            {
                datedaily1 = (Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_datedaily).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


            };


            newloan = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily1, "N-");
            renewal = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily1, "R-");
            redemption = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily1, "FR-");
            partialpayment = dashboardmanager.Get_DailyTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily1, "PP-");

            jewelrysales = dashboardmanager.Get_DailySalesTransaction(Globals.dashboard_request_daily.search_branch, datedaily1, "j");

           
            //newloan
            int newloan_data_id = 0;
            DateTime newloan_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
            decimal newloan_data_debit = 0;
            string newloan_data_txnname = "";
            string newloan_data_branchID = "";
            foreach (var newloan_data in newloan)
            {
                newloan_data_id = newloan_data.ID;
                newloan_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((newloan_data.Transdate).ToString());
                newloan_data_debit = Decimal.Parse((newloan_data.Debit).ToString());
                newloan_data_txnname = newloan_data.TransactionName;
                newloan_data_branchID = newloan_data.BranchID;
            };
            datanewloan = new transaction_details()
            {
                ID = newloan_data_id,
                Transdate = DateTime.Parse(newloan_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                Debit = Decimal.Parse(newloan_data_debit.ToString()),
                TransactionName = newloan_data_txnname,
                BranchID = newloan_data_branchID
            };


            //renewal
            int renewal_data_id = 0;
            DateTime renewal_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
            decimal renewal_data_debit = 0;
            string renewal_data_txnname = "";
            string renewal_data_branchID = "";
            foreach (var renewal_data in renewal)
            {
                renewal_data_id = renewal_data.ID;
                renewal_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((renewal_data.Transdate).ToString());
                renewal_data_debit = Decimal.Parse((renewal_data.Debit).ToString());
                renewal_data_txnname = renewal_data.TransactionName;
                renewal_data_branchID = renewal_data.BranchID;
            };

            datarenewal = new transaction_details()
            {
                ID = renewal_data_id,
                Transdate = DateTime.Parse(renewal_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                Debit = Decimal.Parse(renewal_data_debit.ToString()),
                TransactionName = renewal_data_txnname,
                BranchID = renewal_data_branchID
            };


            //redemption
            int redemption_data_id = 0;
            DateTime redemption_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
            decimal redemption_data_debit = 0;
            string redemption_data_txnname = "";
            string redemption_data_branchID = "";
            foreach (var redemption_data in redemption)
            {
                redemption_data_id = redemption_data.ID;
                redemption_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((redemption_data.Transdate).ToString());
                redemption_data_debit = Decimal.Parse((redemption_data.Debit).ToString());
                redemption_data_txnname = redemption_data.TransactionName;
                redemption_data_branchID = redemption_data.BranchID;
            };

            dataredemption = new transaction_details()
            {
                ID = redemption_data_id,
                Transdate = DateTime.Parse(redemption_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                Debit = Decimal.Parse(redemption_data_debit.ToString()),
                TransactionName = redemption_data_txnname,
                BranchID = redemption_data_branchID
            };

            //partialpayment
            int partialpayment_data_id = 0;
            DateTime partialpayment_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
            decimal partialpayment_data_debit = 0;
            string partialpayment_data_txnname = "";
            string partialpayment_data_branchID = "";
            foreach (var partialpayment_data in partialpayment)
            {
                partialpayment_data_id = partialpayment_data.ID;
                partialpayment_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((partialpayment_data.Transdate).ToString());
                partialpayment_data_debit = Decimal.Parse((partialpayment_data.Debit).ToString());
                partialpayment_data_txnname = partialpayment_data.TransactionName;
                partialpayment_data_branchID = partialpayment_data.BranchID;
            };

            datapartialpayment = new transaction_details()
            {
                ID = partialpayment_data_id,
                Transdate = DateTime.Parse(partialpayment_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                Debit = Decimal.Parse(partialpayment_data_debit.ToString()),
                TransactionName = partialpayment_data_txnname,
                BranchID = partialpayment_data_branchID
            };

            //jewelry_sales
            int jewelry_sales_data_id = 0;
            DateTime jewelry_sales_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((DateTime.Today).ToString());
            decimal jewelry_sales_data_selling = 0;
            string jewelry_sales_data_txntype = "";
            string jewelry_sales_data_branchID = "";
            foreach (var jewelry_sales_data in jewelrysales)
            {
                jewelry_sales_data_id = jewelry_sales_data.ID;
                jewelry_sales_data_transdate = DateTime.Parse((jewelry_sales_data.TxnDateTime).ToString());
                jewelry_sales_data_selling = Decimal.Parse((jewelry_sales_data.SellingPrice).ToString());
                jewelry_sales_data_txntype = jewelry_sales_data.TxnType;
                jewelry_sales_data_branchID = jewelry_sales_data.BranchID;


                datajewelrysales = new transaction_sales_details()
                {
                    ID = jewelry_sales_data_id,
                    TxnDateTime = DateTime.Parse(jewelry_sales_data_transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                    SellingPrice = Decimal.Parse(jewelry_sales_data_selling.ToString()),
                    TxnType = jewelry_sales_data_txntype,
                    BranchID = jewelry_sales_data_branchID
                };

            };

            jewelry_dashboard_view data = new jewelry_dashboard_view()
            {
                transactionnewloan_data = datanewloan,
                transactionrenewal_data = datarenewal,
                transactionredemption_data = dataredemption,
                transactionpartialpayment_data = datapartialpayment,
                transactionjewelrysales_data = datajewelrysales,

                transactionmonthlynewloan_ID = monthly_newloan_data_ID,
                transactionmonthlynewloan_Debit = monthly_newloan_data_debit,

                transactionmonthlyrenewal_ID = monthly_renewal_data_ID,
                transactionmonthlyrenewal_Debit = monthly_renewal_data_debit,


                transactionmonthlyredemption_ID = monthly_redemption_data_ID,
                transactionmonthlyredemption_Debit = monthly_redemption_data_debit,

                transactionmonthlysales_ID = monthly_sales_data_ID,
                transactionmonthlysales_Selling = monthly_sales_data_selling
            };

            _hubContext.Clients.All.updateChart(data);
        };

    }

    public static DashBoardBroadcaster Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
}

[HubName("dashBoardHub")]
public class DashBoardHub : Hub
{
    private DashBoardBroadcaster _broadcaster;
    public DashBoardHub() : this(DashBoardBroadcaster.Instance)
    {
    }
    public DashBoardHub(DashBoardBroadcaster broadcaster)
    {
        _broadcaster = broadcaster;

    }


}
```

> _Layout.chtml

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$.connection.hub.stop();s
        $.connection.hub.qs = { "Name": "value" };
        $.connection.hub.start().done();
    });
</script>
```

> Index.chtml

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    
         
        var dashBoardHub = $.connection.dashBoardHub;
        var days_in_month = new Array(no_of_this_this_month);
        for (var i = 0; i < days_in_month.length; i++) {
            arr_categories.push((i + 1) + " " + month_only_date);
        }

        var arr_daily_data = [];


        dashBoardHub.client.updateChart = function (data) {
            localStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.clear();

            var daily_newloan_data = 0;
            daily_newloan_data = data.transactionnewloan_data.Debit;

            var daily_renewal_data = 0;
            daily_renewal_data = data.transactionrenewal_data.Debit;

            var daily_redemption_data = 0;
            daily_redemption_data = data.transactionredemption_data.Debit;

            var daily_sales_data = 0;
            daily_sales_data = data.transactionjewelrysales_data.SellingPrice;

            const myNodeDaily = document.getElementById("chartdaily");
            while (myNodeDaily.firstChild) {
                myNodeDaily.removeChild(myNodeDaily.lastChild);
            };

            const myNodeMonthly = document.getElementById("chartmonthly");
            while (myNodeMonthly.firstChild) {
                myNodeMonthly.removeChild(myNodeMonthly.lastChild);
            };
             
            var totaltxndaily = parseInt(data.transactionnewloan_data.ID) + parseInt(data.transactionrenewal_data.ID) + parseInt(data.transactionredemption_data.ID) + parseInt(data.transactionjewelrysales_data.ID)
            var totalamtdaily = parseFloat(data.transactionnewloan_data.Debit) + parseFloat(data.transactionrenewal_data.Debit) + parseFloat(data.transactionredemption_data.Debit) + parseFloat(data.transactionjewelrysales_data.SellingPrice);

            //ApexCharts.exec('daily_chart', 'updateSeries', [{
            //    data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
            //}], true);

            //ApexCharts.exec('monthly_chart', 'updateSeries', [{
            //    data: [0, 0, 0, 0,0]
            //}], true);

            arr_daily_data.push(daily_newloan_data, daily_renewal_data, daily_redemption_data, daily_sales_data);

        

            var optionsdaily = {
                colors: ["#008ffb", "#00e396", "#feb019", "#ff4560", "#775dd0"],
                chart: {
                    id:"daily_chart",
                    offsetY: -10,
                    animations: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    type: "donut"
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        customScale: 1,
                        size: 500,
                        donut: {
                            size: '65%',
                            labels: {
                                show: true,
                                name: {
                                    show: true,
                                    fontSize: '30px',
                                    fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                                    color: '#941818',
                                    offsetY: -10
                                },
                                value: {
                                    show: true,
                                    fontSize: '20px',
                                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                                    color: '#941818',
                                    offsetY: 16,
                                    formatter: function (val) {
                                        return Number(val).toMoney()
                                    }
                                },
                                total: {
                                    show: true,
                                    fontSize: '28px',
                                    label: 'Total - ' + totaltxndaily,
                                    color: '#941818',
                                    formatter: function (w) {
                                        return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce((a, b) => {
                                            return Number(totalamtdaily).toMoney()
                                        }, 0)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: arr_daily_data,
                labels: ['Newloan - ' + (data.transactionnewloan_data.ID) + " ", 'Renewal - ' + (data.transactionrenewal_data.ID) + " ", 'Redemption - ' + (data.transactionredemption_data.ID) + " ", 'Sales - ' + (data.transactionjewelrysales_data.ID) + " "],
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    y: {
                        formatter: function (val) {
                            return Number(val).toMoney()
                        },
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    fontSize: '14px',
                    labels: {
                        colors: undefined,
                        useSeriesColors: true
                    },
                },
                responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    options: {
                        chart: {
                            width: 200,
                            height: 300
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'bottom'
                        },
                        plotOptions:
                            {
                                pie:
                                    {
                                        donut:
                                            {
                                                labels:
                                                    {
                                                        name:
                                                            {
                                                                fontSize: '20px'
                                                            },
                                                        value: {
                                                            fontSize: '12px'
                                                        },
                                                        total:
                                                            {
                                                                fontSize: '14px'
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'top',
                            horizontalAlign: 'left'
                        },
                    }
                }]
            };

            var chartdaily = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chartdaily"), optionsdaily);
            chartdaily.render();

            arr_daily_data.length = 0;
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't know to much about SignalR, but shouldn't you call `_hubContext.Clients.Caller.updateChart(data);` instead of `_hubContext.Clients.All.updateChart(data);`?

Comment: I'm new to this signalr. What's the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `_hubContext.Clients.Caller.updateChart(data);` instead of `_hubContext.Clients.All.updateChart(data);`
The difference is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> The Hub class has a Clients property that contains the following properties for communication between server and client:
> All: Calls a method on all connected clients
> Caller: Calls a method on the client that invoked the hub method
> Others: a method on all connected clients except the client that invoked the method

Comment: ihubconnectioncontext dynamic does not contain a definition for caller

Comment: i dont know why?